# how to delete multiple folders using google drive api in javascript with axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to delete multiple files of google drive using google drive api but it give 404 error

```
axios.delete('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files',{
         params:{
             fileId:'1nJddic7Gc_x8NQBzwOPhglwfYI-_Ms5E,1nJddic7Gc_x8NQBzwOPhglwfYI-_Ms5E',
              supportsTeamDrives: 'false',
         },
         headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
        })
        .then(res=>{    console.log(res.data)   })
        .catch(err=>{    console.log(err)   })
```

Comment: I'm accessing google drive using Axios. its work fine when I get files and folder from google drive @jabba

Comment: I can't find the `DELETE` verb in the documentation. Where did you find it?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/delete

Comment: That's the documentation for v2 API. You're using v3 in your code.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete

Comment: The call is `DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId`. You are sending `DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fileId=fileId&supportsTeamDrives=false`. Keep in mind that `supportsTeamDrives` is deprecated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242218/discussion-between-air-university-and-jabaa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the `fileId` as path parameter:

```
axios.delete('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1nJddic7Gc_x8NQBzwOPhglwfYI-_Ms5E,1nJddic7Gc_x8NQBzwOPhglwfYI-_Ms5E', {
  headers: {
    authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
  }
})
.then(res => { console.log(res.data); })
.catch(err => { console.log(err); });
```

Comment: still gives same 404 error

Comment: @AirUniversity Are you sure the file ID is correct?

Comment: it work fine if we remove the params fields @jabaa

Comment: but it works for single files if we want to delete multiple folders in a single?

Comment: @AirUniversity The documentation says: _"Permanently deletes **a file**"_ I don't see a method to delete mulitple elements. It looks like you have to send multiple requests. But you can delete a folder: _" If the target is a folder, all descendants owned by the user are also deleted."_

Comment: `axios.delete('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1nJddic7Gc_x8NQBzwOPhglwfYI-_Ms5E',{headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`}})then(res=>{    console.log(res.data)   }).catch(err=>{    console.log(err)   })` delete params  this query work fine